# Does the require function need more gas when called with a message?

Tags: gas, require

If I add a message to `require` as a second parameter, will it increase gas consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Aquila's contract to perform more tests.

### Contract

#### V1

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Sharer {
    function sendHalf() public payable {
        require(msg.value % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

#### V2

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Sharer {
    function sendHalf() public payable {
        require(msg.value % 2 == 0, "zonk bonk");
    }
}
```

### Deployment

#### V1

```
{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "26800",
        "executionCost": "81",
        "totalCost": "26881"
    },
    "External": {
        "sendHalf()": "133"
    }
}
```

#### V2

```
{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "46400",
        "executionCost": "99",
        "totalCost": "46499"
    },
    "External": {
        "sendHalf()": "228"
    }
}
```

V2 needs a whopping **19618** more gas at deployment:

### Transaction

Importantly, there's no difference in gas costs when transfering an even number of `wei` to the contract. However, when the number is odd and `require` reverts the transaction...

`V1` consumed 21401 gas while `V2` 21500, the difference being **99**. It's not a huge figure, but neither a trivial one. I guess convenience has a cost!

Answer (score 3):

**I did small test in Remix**

Here is small contract

```
contract Sharer {
    function sendHalf(address addr) public payable {
        require(msg.value % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Gas estimation **without** message:

```
{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "32000",
        "executionCost": "81",
        "totalCost": "32081"
    },
    "External": {
        "sendHalf(address)": "147"
    }
}
```

Gas estimation **with** message:

```
{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "51600",
        "executionCost": "105",
        "totalCost": "51705"
    },
    "External": {
        "sendHalf(address)": "240"
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean that it's okay to use revert messages on testnets, but, ideally, use as few as possible in production?

Comment: that is personal choice. if you use messages in dapp logic you will need these in production